# Realm.io. How to refresh replaced realm?

Tags: ios, realm

I've just created a dropBox backup/restore in my Realm based iOS app. I'm replacing current defaultRealm with the imported one. If I kill the app and restart it, everything works as expected and I see my new imported data but I can't make it appears without restarting the app (even when I've checked the old realm file has been deleted and recreated).

I've tried to reassign the realm path at RLMRealmConfiguration and update the schema version to perform a migration but nothing changes. Is there any way to force a realm to refresh data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to reliably switch the Realm file is to make sure your app has no strong references to any `RLMRealm` on any thread.

If you can guarantee this, then at this point if you delete the underlying Realm file (including the associated files, such as the lock file) and save the new file to that path, you can then call `[RLMRealm defaultRealm]` and retrieve the new data.

Here's some code to delete all the associated Realm files:

```c
NSString *path = [RLMRealm defaultRealmPath];

NSString *fileName = path.lastPathComponent;

NSString *folderPath = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];

NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:folderPath];

// Enumerate all the files in the folder containing the Realm file    
for (NSString *filePath in enumerator) {
    // Check to find all the associated Realm files
    if ([filePath containsString:fileName]) {
        NSString *fullPath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath];

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:fullPath error:nil];
    }
}
```

This issue tracks adding a safe way to delete a Realm file into the API: [Issue #2422](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2422)

Comment: Hi Adam. Thank you for answering. I'm currently using [NSFileManager defaultManager] replaceItemAtURL… to replace a entire folder (which contains the default realm and an image folder) with the unzipped downloaded folder. The process completes without error so I supposed every associated files were deleted too. I'll try the way you wrote as soon as possible. In fact, it seems a good idea to add a native method to do that. Thank you again

Comment: No problem. Using my way isn't necessary, but glad it is helpful. The main point is that to remove the file behind `[RLMRealm defaultRealm]`, you must make sure to not have any strong references to any `RLMRealm` instance returned from that on any thread. If you can guarantee that, then you can safely delete all of its associated files.

Comment: @AdamFish how do you ensure that there are no strong references? I find this very tricky to do. I don't even store realm objects in my controllers, but still have problems that the realm is not refreshed until I kill the app.

Comment: ARC doesn't make this entirely easy. The only way to guarantee you have no references is to wrap accessing Realm objects in an @autoreleasepool to ensure they are cleaned up immediately. Personally, I would not try to replace Realms, but just create additional Realm at different paths... then just make sure your controllers can be passed in a Realm. You can then safely delete the old Realm files on startup before anything has accessed it.

Comment: @AdamFish different paths is not really something you can do if you want to enable users to backup and restore realm files :/ 

Autorelease pools did not help in my case. It seems as if all persisted objects also have a reference to the realm itself. As long as I clear all persisted objects from memory when the view disappears I am able to replace the realm file without restarting the app. Pretty annoying though as it prevents me from passing persisted realm objects between viewcontrollers.